# SQLite Increment Default Column Value on Insert

Tags: laravel, sqlite, insert, increment

### Background / Laravel Info

Feel free to skip ahead to the question. I have an exception handler that tracks the number of attempts to make an API call. If the call fails, I increment the number of attempts and save the exception error to a database table. This setup allows us to run a scheduled Artisan command and stop trying a specific call if it fails a certain number of times. Currently, I am using Laravel's updateOrCreate method in the handler:

```
try {
    Vmi::createPurchaseOrder($purchaseOrder);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    PurchaseOrder::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'invoice_id' => $purchaseOrder->invoice_id
        ],
        [
            'error'    => $e->getMessage(),
            'attempts' => DB::raw('attempts + 1'),
        ]
    );
}
```

The relevant columns in the table are:

- invoice_id unsigned int
- error text
- attempts unsigned int default 0

In MySQL, this seems to work fine, but I recently switched my tests to an in-memory SQLite database, which doesn't like the fact that the insert statement attempts to increment a column value. I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: attempts
```

### SQLite Question

Is there a way to increment the default value of a column in SQLite when performing an insert?

```
-- I suppose this is kind of odd, but it works in MySQL and does not work in SQLite.

insert into purchase_orders (
    invoice_id,
    error,
    attempts
) values (
    1,
    'Invalid customer ID',
    attempts + 1
);

-- Of course, this works as expected.

update purchase_orders
set attempts = attempts + 1
where invoice_id = 1;
```

Comment: Can't you just always insert `1`?

Comment: That would be an easy fix, but the raw SQL is generated by the Laravel method. I guess I don't know if this should be considered a Laravel "bug" or if I just shouldn't use the method.

Comment: How do you mean that? Why can't you use `'attempts' => 1`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I am calling updateOrCreate() in my code because I'm not sure if a record with a specific invoice ID already exists. If a record does exist, I want whatever value is stored in the column to be incremented, otherwise, a value of 1 is fine. But Laravel is generating the query (either an update or an insert statement), and in this case, the insert statement fails when using SQLite.

Comment: I'm leaning towards just not being able to use updateOrCreate with an increment statement. It would be less code for me, but I can see why it wouldn't make sense to combine these.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/updateorcreate-increment-value-depending-on-update-or-set-to-1-if-its-an-insert

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!